# Approximate Bayesian computation: where to start from?

Tags: bayesian, references, approximate-bayesian-computation

I am about to start a project in **ABC methods** and I need to first of all study ABC since I know nothing about it. I spent quite a bit looking for on-line tutorials and notes but I found nothing apart for some videos. Can you please suggest me some notes or even a textbook? Not to difficult since I do not really need to understand all the math behind it. I am looking for some material that could allow me to understand the reasons behind the use of ABC methods.

Answer (score 7):

There are many introductions to ABC, available, most of them on arXiv, so I am rather surprised the OP could only find videos! I agree with the earlier answer that the Wikipedia entry is very good; it actually stemmed from a [PLoS Computational Biology](http://journals.plos.org/ploscompbiol/article?id=10.1371/journal.pcbi.1002803) article (that I refereed). In addition to Mark Beaumont's superb review, let me refer the OP to the [depository of ABC related papers](https://approximatebayesiancomputational.wordpress.com/). Which was run by [Erkan Buzbas](http://www.erkanbuzbas.com/) from the University of Idaho till 2015. For more recent papers and extensions, you may check the 2015 and 2016 [NIPS workshops](https://sites.google.com/site/abcinmontreal/) on the topic, the [ABC'ruise](http://www.hiit.fi/ABCruise/) workshop, and our supremely recent [ABC'ory workshop](http://www.birs.ca/events/2017/5-day-workshops/17w5025) at BIRS, Banff, that contains [videos](http://www.birs.ca/events/2017/5-day-workshops/17w5025/videos) for most talks.

Some chapters of [The Handbook of Approximate Bayesian Computation](https://www.amazon.co.uk/Approximate-Computation-Monographs-Statistics-Probability/dp/1439881502/ref=sr_1_2?ie=UTF8&qid=1488572734&sr=8-2&keywords=approximate%20bayesian) edited by Sisson, Fan and Beaumont are available on arXiv as well, and the book should be out very soon.

The slides of several courses I gave on ABC are to be found on slideshare and range [from one hour to ten hours presentations](https://www.slideshare.net/search/slideshow?searchfrom=header&q=ABC%20xianblog%20Bayes&ud=any&ft=all&lang=en&sort=).

Comment: Besides the slides, are your talks available anywhere as videos? I recall seeing one somewhere but I don't remember where...

Comment: @Tim: I found [a video of my AISTATS 2014/MLSS tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=8TGkrkK6pq4) [2h]. And another one of [my ISBA "Foundation Lecture"](http://videolectures.net/isba2012_robert_bayesian_computation/) in 2012.

Answer (score 5):

Actually a *great* starting point is the very detailed Wikipedia article on the [Approximate Bayesian Computation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Approximate_Bayesian_computation) plus the enormous number of references below it (many of them are available online).

Check also the nice introductory [blog entry](http://www.sumsar.net/blog/2014/10/tiny-data-and-the-socks-of-karl-broman/) by Rasmus Bååth and accompanying [video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=nKCT-Cdk0xY) and [slides from UseR! 2015 conference](http://www.sumsar.net/files/academia/rasmus_baath_user_2015_karls_socks_and_abc_short.pdf).

The *[Handbook of Approximate Bayesian Computation](https://www.amazon.co.uk/Approximate-Computation-Monographs-Statistics-Probability/dp/1439881502/ref=sr_1_2?ie=UTF8&qid=1488572734&sr=8-2&keywords=approximate%20bayesian)* by Sisson, Fan and Beaumont is not yet available but it is ought to be published Chapman & Hall/CRC this year.

Answer (score 2):

When I looked over the topic a few years ago I found the best review to be [Approximate Bayesian Computation in Evolution and Ecology by Mark A. Beaumont](http://www.annualreviews.org/doi/pdf/10.1146/annurev-ecolsys-102209-144621).

Another good review (which focuses on MCMC methods for ABC) can be found in the [Handbook of Markov Chain Monte Carlo](http://www.mcmchandbook.net/HandbookTableofContents.html) chapter 12 (Likelihood-free Markov chain Monte Carlo by Scott A. Sisson and Yanan Fan.)